# Is there an API for implementing a feature like in Mobile Safari where I can concurrently run several instances of my app in the app?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, multiple-instances

In Mobile Safari, you can open up multiple different windows, and navigate between them in sort of a zoomed out view. I have also seen this functionality in a few other apps as well.

Is there an API for doing this? I have an app that I'd like to integrate this functionality into, and I was hoping I could get a clue where to start by coming here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of your app is one, i think mobile safari use multiple views (UIWebView), not multiple windows; you have to play with UIPageControl and UIScrollView to recreate the safari effect in case you want display a webpage; use UIViews instead if you want display some button/image/etc.